# How to allow the sync local data and cloud from database for an mobile app?

Tags: sql, database, react-native, redux, mobile

Good morning everyone!

I am working on a project of mobile app, and for that I have to use a database and some functions to allow the sync between the local and server data and so allow an offline and online working app.

The mobile app is based on **React Native** and need a **structured database** (so, no NoSQL). During my scearchs, I have found two potentials solutions:

- React Native Async Storage (https://reactnative.dev/docs/security#async-storage) ;
- React Redux with package like react-native-offline and redux-offline (https://blog.logrocket.com/creating-offline-first-react-native-app/) ;
- Microsoft Sync Framework (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previousversions/sql/synchronization/sync-framework-2.1/) ;

But, I don't know what is the best solution. Do you have some advices to choice the best database and packages to do that, please?

Have a good day!

Comment: If you have alot of data to handle, Async storage might not be a good idea to store data. Perhaps you can look into sqllite, it works similarly to a sql database.

Comment: The problem with SQLite is he don't give me the possibility to sync between the local and server data to allow an offline and online working app.